# Error when trying to add an entry into SQLite table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

This is the error I get when I trying to add an entry:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteExeption:near "TABLELocation":syntax error(code1):,while compiling: CREATE TABLELocation(idInteger PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nameTEXT NOT NULL, detailTEXT NOT NULL
```

The query to create the table is:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" + DBTable +
    "("+ key_rowID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
    key_name + "TEXT NOT NULL," + key_detail + "TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

where `DBTable = "table_name"`. How to solve the problem?

Comment: `nameTEXT`. Missed a space (3 actually). extra tip : read the error, it contains the solution

Answer (score 3):

You missed a space: try `db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DBTable + ...`

Answer (score 1):

I believe yo forgot spaces between the variables and the text right behind that. Could you try this query?

```
CREATE TABLE " + DBTable + "("+ key_rowID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + key_name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + key_detail + " TEXT NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is missing spaces! `"CREATE TABLE" + DBTable` results in `TABLELocation`.

Check the complete string, you have multiple missing spaces there.